# Custom char_filter for pattern in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and trying to create custom plugin and register custom analyzer (with custom char_filter) to tokenize following patterns.
e.g.

"TOM 1-23" 
will generate tokens
"TOM 1"
"TOM 2"
to
"TOM 23"

"PETA A-G" 
will generate tokens
"PETA A"
"PETA B"
to
"PETA G"

Can anyone please suggest how to create this custom char_filter? Any resources that would help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think [this blog post](http://www.citrine.io/blog/2015/2/14/building-a-custom-analyzer-in-lucene) will be helpful. He has also given [this code sample](https://github.com/CitrineInformatics/plugin-plussign/tree/master/io/citrine/pluginplussign) in github.

P.S. I haven't tried this yet. I just went over this and seems like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom analysis plugin. A custom analysis plugin can be written by extending `org.elasticsearch.plugins.Plugin` class and implementing `org.elasticsearch.plugins.AnalysisPlugin` interface. Override the `getTokenFilters`, `getTokenizers`, `getAnalyzers` methods as required to implement your own tokenization logic. Refer to [this analysis plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/plugins/analysis-nori/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/analysis/nori/AnalysisNoriPlugin.java) for details around required changes.